# Not Compiling When Using Pointer to Function

Tags: c++

My code compiles and runs fine when I incorporate all of this as a single file. However, when I use a header file and use separate files, I get this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "someClass::newNode()", referenced from:
      _main in check.o
      someClass::insert(someClass::Node*, char const*, char const*) in entry.o
ld: sym
```

bol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

I have tried everything and I cannot find what the issue is. They compile separately using "-c" but linking the object files gives me the error. Also, I am using inclusion guards and all the suggested tips when including header files. Any help would be appreciated!

```
//.h file
class someClass{
    public:
    //other stuff
    struct Node
    {
    //...
    };

    Node *newNode();
};

//entry.C
Node someClass::newNode(){
    someClass::Node *bNode = new someClass::Node;
    //...
    return bNode;
}

//check.C
int main(){
    //...
    someClass obj;
    someClass.Node *root = obj.newNode();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Show us your command for building the program because that's what's going wrong

Comment: also I don't think that's the real code example because it is missing headers and will not compile. why did you change it?

Comment: It seems you object file is not compiled and you missed compiler errors. The returned type is not the same as declared: `Node someClass::newNode()` vs. `Node *newNode();`.

Comment: My command is g++ entry.C check.C . I think the issue is that the method Node *newNode returns a pointer and something to do with when I try to use obj.newNode(). I only incorporated the code that has issues using the method!

Comment: @S.M. I also think that is the issue. I am unsure how to invoke the method if the method returns a pointer like *newNode does.

Answer (score 0):

For getting nested type in c++ use "::" instead of "."

```
someClass::Node *root = obj.newNode();
```

Comment: I get the following error doing that:

spellcheck.C:13:40: error: call to non-static member function without an object
      argument
    dictentry::Node *root = dictentry::newNode();

That is why I created the obj, but still does not work unfortunately.